# Нажатие в DatagridView флажка Checkbox являющимся объектом DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

Прошу помощи!
Есть у меня таблица, в ней есть столбец Boоlean.

В событие Чекбокса хочу рассчитывать количество выполненных и не выполненных заданий и отображать это на ProgressBar

```
DataColumn BoolColumn = new DataColumn("Готово", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
Taskk.Columns.Add(BoolColumn);
dataview1.Table = dataSet1.Tables["Taskk"];
dataview1.RowFilter = $"Имя = '{comboBox2.Text}'";
dataGridView2.DataSource = dataview1;
```

**Вопрос:**
**Какое событие отвечает за нажатие на этот чекбокс?**

Дело в том, что при активации флажка, события из Datagridview вроде CellValueChanged не срабатывают пока я не нажму на любую соседную строку. И лишь после выделения любой строки срабатывает событие и Datatable узнает, что значение изменилось. Мне же нужно, чтобы прогресс бар реагировал сразу, при нажатии чекбокса.

Помогите пожалуйста сделать все правильно. Я новичок, и искал инфу, но пока не получается.

пробовал [DataTable.ColumnChanged Event MDSN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columnchanged?view=net-5.0)

Как мне организовать этот процесс правильно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине видно, что при нажатых чекбоксах прогресс бар видит 2 нажатых и одну нет.

Спасибо тем, кто откликнулся

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, было сложно, но разобрался )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в одном проекте сделано вот так.

```cs
// изменение поведения DGV
private void DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        // здесь обработка состояний чекбоксов
    }
}
```