# Передавать индекс выделенной ячейки в access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

На форме существует `DataGridView`, куда я вывожу таблицу с `bool` значениями, допустим, их 5. Если пользователь выбрал ячейку, мне нужно выводить индекс выбранной ячейки в `Label`, иначе индекс убирать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал создать массив, куда помещаю значения выбранных индексов и потом с помощью `string.Join` вывожу в `Label`, но выводятся так же и пустые значения, которые мне не нужны.

Пробовал по другому, но тут вообще не выходит

```cs
int[] places = new int[5];

private void placesDGV_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == placesDGV.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (placesDGV.SelectedCells[e.RowIndex].Selected)
    {
        places[placesDGV.SelectedCells[e.RowIndex].ColumnIndex] = (placesDGV.SelectedCells[e.RowIndex].ColumnIndex + 1).ToString();
        sessChoosenPlacesLab.Text = "";
        sessChoosenPlacesLab.Text += places[e.RowIndex];
        //Варик с join
        //sessChoosenPlacesLab.Text += string.Join(", ", places);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209760/373567)

Comment: Да, спасибки большое