# Отключить выбор ячейки DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

На форме есть DataGridView, в котором набор флажков, взятых запросом из БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать отключение ячейки, которая выносится на форму ТОЛЬКО запросом, если флажок в ней в состоянии true?
То есть, к примеру, в БД выделенная ячейка будет в состоянии true, я запросом вывожу их в DGV, она отключается для выбора и пользователь не может изменить ее состояние на форме

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нажатие в DatagridView флажка Checkbox являющимся объектом DataTable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209741/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-datagridview-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-checkbox-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-datatable)

Comment: В прилинкованном ответе показано, как сделать так, чтобы вызывался обработчик события для чекбокса из DGV. В обработчике вы сможете задать уже нужное вам поведение.